# How to predict new data using a trained simple feed forward neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Forgive me if this sounds like a dumb question. Assuming that I have a neural network that is trained with the data of shape [m, n], How do I test the trained network with data of shape [1, 3]

here is the code that I currently have:

```
n_hidden_1 = 1024
n_hidden_2 = 1024
n = len(test_data[0]) - 1
m = len(test_data)

alpha = 0.005
training_epoch = 1000
display_epoch = 100

train_X = np.array([i[:-1:] for i in test_data]).astype('float32')
train_X = normalize_data(train_X)
train_Y = np.array([i[-1::] for i in test_data]).astype('float32')
train_Y = normalize_data(train_Y)

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[m, n])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[m, 1])

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, 1]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])),
}

layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)

activation = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(activation - Y)) / (2 * m)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(alpha).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(training_epoch):
        sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
        cost_ = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
        if epoch % display_epoch == 0:
            print('Epoch:', epoch, 'Cost:', cost_)
```

How do I test a new data? For regression I know I can use something like this for the data `[0.4, 0.5, 0.1]`

```
predict_x = np.array([0.4, 0.5, 0.1], dtype=np.float32).reshape([1, 3])
predict_x = (predict_x - mean) / std
predict_y = tf.add(tf.matmul(predict_x, W), b)
result = sess.run(predict_y).flatten()[0]
```

How do I do the same with a neural network?

Comment: What do the dimensions `[m, n]` stand for? Is `m` number of samples and `n` number of features?

Comment: @kaufmanu yup 720 by 3

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[None, n])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[None, 1])
```

the first dimension of those two placeholders will have variable size, i.e. at training time it can be different (e.g. 720) than at test time (e.g. 1). This is often referred to as having "variable batch sizes" as it is quite common to have different batch sizes during training and testing.

On this line:

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(activation - Y)) / (2 * m)
```

you are making use of `m` which is now variable. to make this line work with variable batch sizes (as `m` is now unknown before execution of the graph) you should do something like:

```
m = tf.shape(X)[0]
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(activation - Y)) / (tf.multiply(m, 2))
```

`tf.shape` evaluates the dynamic shape of `X`, i.e. the shape it has at runtime.